# storage key not a valid base64 encoding - azure storage - android

Tags: android, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a text blob to azure storage blob using the following code:

```
public static final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;"
        + "AccountName=MY_STORAGE_ACNT;"
        + "AccountKey=[MYKEY]";


CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("ubiety");

        container.createIfNotExists();
        BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
        containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);
        container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);
        CloudBlockBlob blob1 = container.getBlockBlobReference("storage_name");
        blob1.uploadText("Hello, World1");
```

This is a mere copy paste of the sample at [BlobBasics Sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage-samples/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/gettingstarted/BlobBasics.java), still

I get the error

> StorageKey is not a valid Base64 Encoded string.

Can someone please help. I am very sure, i am using the correct key provided at the azure portal

Thank you.

Comment: Are you including the = signs at the end of the key string given in the portal?

Comment: it's either your keys are wrong or you have included the = sign in the keys

Comment: You have to exclude [] from AccountKey it should be 
public static final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
            + "AccountName=accountname;"
            + "AccountKey=yourKey";

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the sample link you've given it looks like you're using the [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) Storage library rather than the [Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android) Storage library. If you use the Android storage library and it's associated [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage-samples/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/samples/blob/BlobGettingStartedTask.java) that should work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I got this message as well and it turned out I was using the wrong key. I was using the shared access signature obtained from the azure storage explorer. That's wrong. You need to grab the key from the azure portal. Go to the dashboard. 
Select your storage account. You can then select "Access keys". Just pick the top key.

Then run code like this ( Scala, but Python is possible too )

```
var storage_account_name:String = = "storageaccountname"
// This is key1 from access keys in my user interface
var storage_account_access_key: String = "UU8udCiTs/3CEmjH3xVVFtSR7EAWZifGlSf3QoNNUDYL2GjxQ4mQ3GhuoZvO8G/eO9Z+SgY1uXrVBGHBc5u7tA=="

spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",
  storage_account_access_key)
spark.read.format("csv").load("wasbs://blobname@storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/csvfile.csv")
```

In the example `storageaccountname` is the name of my storage account. `blobname` is the name of the blob in the storage account.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Azure Account Keys with forward slash (/) does not work. See  https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/3135

What I did -

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey creds =
                new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, key_with_slash);
com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount   account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

on linux you can use the base64 program and it worked for me. Do not include the % at the end

```
echo -n '<ONE OF YOUR ACCESS KEY FROM BLOB STORAGE ACCOUNT>' | base64 -w 0
```